# How to write something in sure fire reports without using Assert?

Tags: maven, selenium, junit4, surefire

I am using Junit and Maven along with selenium. For reporting i am using surefire plugin. My requirement is to update the surefire reports with message on failure. It can be done using `Assert` but it will abort the test case. But i dont want to abort it but to just report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the maven.test.failure.ignore property (system property on command line) like:

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

or to ignore failures during build process you can use the configuration for the [maven-surefire-plugin:](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)

```
<configuration>
  .
  <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
  .
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, it will just not fail the build itself.

Comment: But i don't recommend it, cause you should get your tests fixed ;-)

Comment: In my case that's not because test case is failing, it's because AUT is not passing certain criteria and we gotta report that.

Comment: It is still aborting the test case. :(

Comment: I don't want to abort the test case. But want to report it. Is it doable?

Comment: Ah sorry ,but if your assert says it's value is not as expected that the test does not fulfill the assert condition? The failed tests will be reported. So what would you like to do?

Comment: @khmarbaise, when using a CI system, you want to distinguish between a failed run and a failed test. Also having a full test run instead of a partial run with one failure is very beneficial, because one error message could be misleading, you know if problem impacts many areas or only a limited one, etc. It is not that simple to say, fix your tests or fix your product.